# Correção da palavra "ontem" no medidor de tempo da pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

A palavra 'ontem', não tem acento, ao contrário do que está presente aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: por falta de referência mais [fidedigna](http://www.portuguesnarede.com/2008/11/acento-nas-palavras-com-em-no-fim.html)...